# Converting the text to time and calculating average time on that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

```
15 h 11 m 59  s
48 h 11 m 59  s
```

I need to convert the above text to "48:11:59"(Time format) and apply the average function on that. Can any one help on that?

Comment: Excel converts it correctly, just you need to set the correct formatting. See the similar question for the solution.

Comment: Im not able to do so. Can you please help me with the above example.

Comment: What is exactly your issue with it? What've you tried, what was the result instead of the desired one?

Comment: First i need to convert the above text to 15:11:59, 48:11:59. Then I need to get the average on that as "31:41:59".

Comment: "What've you tried, what was the result instead of the desired one?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question at face value, let's assume you have the value `"15 h 11 m 59 s 48 h 11 m 59 s"` in cell `A1` representing two durations and you want to find the average:

[image: TextToTimeAverage]

Format cells B2:D2 as `[h]:mm:ss` - this means they will store time values which can go over 24 hours (i.e. durations, not times of day).

Then use these formulae to calculate the figures you need:

- B2: `=LEFT(A2,2) & ":" & MID(A2,6,2) & ":" & MID(A2,11,2)`
- C2: `=MID(A2,16,2) & ":" & MID(A2,21,2) & ":" & MID(A2,26,2)`
- D2: `=(C2+B2)/COUNTA(B2:C2)`